# The OP Seemed Genuinely Curious: Couldn't An Edit Have Saved This Question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

[Can applications affect power consumption in a substantial way?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156740/reducing-power-consumption)

Indeed, as currently constituted, this question probably *should* be closed.

Yet the OP seemed genuinely curious, and the answers and comments that were provided were exactly what the OP was looking for.

Couldn't a well-placed edit have saved this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Jarrod Roberson actually did a good edit too it to make it a good constructive question.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/156740/revisions

I went ahead and reopened it.